# Toggling DIV with checked radio button

Tags: jquery

I am trying to toggle a `DIV` according to selection of `radio buttons`. This is my coding..

```
<div class="form-element-row">
    <div class="first-child">
        <label for="name">Registration Period :</label>
    </div>
    <div class="last-child">
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="1" />1 Year
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="2" />2 Years
        <input type="radio"  name="period"  value="3" />3 Years                             
    </div>
</div>

<div class="subscription_rate">
    <div class="first-child">
        <label>&nbsp;</label>
    </div>
    <div class="last-child">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Subscription Rate</th>
            <th>1 Year</th>
            <th>2 Years</th>
            <th>3 Years</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Rates for subscription period.</td>
            <td>$ 3000</td>
            <td>$ 4500</td>
            <td>$ 7500</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is jquery

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    if($('input[type=radio]:checked')){
        $('.subscription_rate') .slideToggle('slow') // show it when user clicks the radio buttons
    }else{
        $('.subscription_rate') .fadeOut("slow");  // if in any case radio button is not checked by user hide the div
        }
});
```

This is working for me but have a problem.. Here I need to toggle only clicking on selected `radio button`. With this code its working for every button.. That mean just think I want to select next radio button then it toggle down the DIV. What I need to do with this is  always I am selecting a radio button I need to toggle up the `DIV`.

Can anybody tell me how can I do this.. 
Thank you.

Comment: you want a radio button to make a div always visible and other to make it hidden always and not to toggle? is this is what you are looking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var i = 0;
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
     if(i==0) {
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $(".subscription_rate").slideDown();
         i++;
     }
     else {
     if($(this).hasClass("active")) {
         $(".subscription_rate").slideToggle();
     }
     else {
         $(".active").removeClass("active");
         $(this).addClass("active");
         $(".subscription_rate").show().fadeOut().fadeIn();
     }
     }
});
```

[***Working Fiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/3UBE4/3/)

You can add class 'active' and next time if a user clicks it will detect whether it has class 'active' or not.

Comment: you want to fadeOut() or slideUp() ?

Comment: now see http://jsfiddle.net/3UBE4/1/ that buddy and one more question when you click on other button do you want it to slideDown or just remain as it is?

Comment: Again working first time. Then I need to click twice to toggle up in my second time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23153/discussion-between-aspiring-aqib-and-tharanga-nuwan)

Answer (score 1):

This code will do the required functionality.

```
    $('.subscription_rate').hide();
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
     if($('input[type=radio]:checked') && $(this).attr('value')==1){
         if(!($('.subscription_rate').is(':visible'))){
             $('.subscription_rate').slideToggle('slow')
         }
     }else if($('input[type=radio]:checked') && $(this).attr('value')==2){
         $('.subscription_rate') .fadeOut("slow");
     }
    else if(!($('.subscription_rate').is(':visible'))){
       $('.subscription_rate').slideToggle('slow');
     }
});
```

The radio button 1 & 3 will always makes the div visible and 2 will always hide the div.

Comment: This code not working for my expected way. when checking next button it toggle down the DIV

Comment: For example if there are 3 radio buttons, what is your requirement on this three buttons.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a simple solution, if it IS checked , slide it up, otherwise not, fade it out.  That way, if you change it through code, it should have the same effect (Radio buttons cannot "unselect all" on a click, only through code.

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        $('.subscription_rate').slideDown("slow");
    } else {
        $('.subscription_rate').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

EDIT:

Here is a fiddle with a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/AVgzW/ - note it is `slideDown` not toggleDown - and you could use `slideUp` of that is desired - doc: http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

EDIT2:

1 If it is already selected and you click it, it shows/hides the div/text on a toggle.

2 If it is NOT already selected (select new option), it hides it (the div text)

3 Initial selection of ANY will not show the text, but will once it is selected and clicked again.

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
$('input[type=radio]').change(function () {
    if ($(this).is(':checked') && $(this).hasClass("activeSelection")) {
        $('.subscription_rate').slideToggle("slow");
    } else {
        $('input[type=radio]').removeClass("activeSelection");
        $(this).addClass('activeSelection');
        $('.subscription_rate').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Fiddle for that:  http://jsfiddle.net/AVgzW/1/

Comment: If this is not the desired effect, please reclarify your question with more details/clear explaination of results desired and we can surely assist you!

Comment: I need to add effect toggle up and down to only selected button. When I check new one it should toggle up

Answer (score 1):

I think you want each radio button to show each element individually? If so this code works and you can check it out on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hbHqj/1/)

I added classes to the individual elements to control them seperately:

```
<tr>
  <th>Subscription Rate</th>
  <th class="toggle 1yr">1 Year</th>
  <th class="toggle 2yr">2 Years</th>
  <th class="toggle 3yr">3 Years</th>
</tr>
```

This js will only show the items relative to the radio button you selected.

```
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
$('input[type=radio]').click(function () {
  $('.subscription_rate').show();
  $('.toggle').hide(); // if in any case radio button is not checked by user hide the div
  $('.' + $(this).val() + 'yr').show();
});
```

I would recommend not using table elements if you want them to look nice and have fancy transitions.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if this is what your looking for but this might help:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('.subscription_rate').hide(); // hide the div first
 $('input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    if($('input[type=radio]:checked')){
        $('.subscription_rate') .show('slow') // show it when user clicks the radio buttons
    }else{
        $('.subscription_rate') .fadeOut("slow");  // if in any case radio button is not checked by user hide the div
        }
});})
```